# Is it possible to run maui app for tizen tv 4.0?

Tags: visual-studio, maui, tizen

I have hard time to run MAUI app on tizen tv 4.0

I got the following error, when I run app on emulator:

[image]

I need to target old version, so I can't change device os. Sure, It works on tizen tv 7.0

Could you tell me if MAUI support tizen tv 4.0? It will be great to hear how to set up if it is possible.

Thank you in advance

I expect Visual Studio MAUI support old version of tizen tv

Comment: You would have a better time if you asked this here https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET MAUI apps are only compatible with Tizen 7.0 or higher versions with .NET 6.0 applied. Unfortunately, it is not supported on older Tizen version TVs.